# Using UIEditMenuInteraction with WebKit

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios16, uimenucontroller

I use UIMenuController when presenting my custom menu for the selected text on my WKWebview. But it is now deprecated on iOS 16, and get the following error

```
[Text] Using UIMenuController to add items into text menus is deprecated. Please implement the UITextInput API editMenuForTextRange:suggestedActions: instead.

[EditMenuInteraction] The edit menu ... did not have performable commands and/or actions; ignoring present.
```

And now I cant find any documentation on how to customize the menu on wkwebview.

This is what I am trying to present on the menu.

[image]

How can you customize the menu on the selected text on wkwebview?

I tried adding UITextInput, but it requires to conform to a bunch of protocols.

Comment: Hello. I saw that you are also using `FolioReaderKit`. I have a problem with text highlighting. Could you check my question? Surely you solved this problem. I have a lot of errors with `primaryKey` but now my problem in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745605/swift-exc-bad-access-with-using-realm-and-folioreaderkit Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while presenting my custom menu in webview in iOS 16.
I implemented the following method and removed all non-required menu items as following and it was good to go:

```
    open override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        builder.remove(menu: .lookup)
        builder.remove(menu: .file)
        builder.remove(menu: .edit)
        builder.remove(menu: .view)
        builder.remove(menu: .window)
        builder.remove(menu: .help)
        builder.remove(menu: .about)
        builder.remove(menu: .preferences)
        builder.remove(menu: .services)
        builder.remove(menu: .hide)
        builder.remove(menu: .quit)
        builder.remove(menu: .newScene)
        builder.remove(menu: .openRecent)
        builder.remove(menu: .close)
        builder.remove(menu: .print)
        builder.remove(menu: .document)
        builder.remove(menu: .undoRedo)
        builder.remove(menu: .standardEdit)
        builder.remove(menu: .find)
        builder.remove(menu: .replace)
        builder.remove(menu: .share)
        builder.remove(menu: .textStyle)
        builder.remove(menu: .spelling)
        builder.remove(menu: .spellingPanel)
        builder.remove(menu: .spellingOptions)
        builder.remove(menu: .substitutions)
        builder.remove(menu: .substitutionsPanel)
        builder.remove(menu: .substitutionOptions)
        builder.remove(menu: .transformations)
        builder.remove(menu: .speech)
        builder.remove(menu: .learn)
        builder.remove(menu: .format)
        builder.remove(menu: .font)
        builder.remove(menu: .textSize)
        builder.remove(menu: .textColor)
        builder.remove(menu: .textStylePasteboard)
        builder.remove(menu: .text)
        builder.remove(menu: .writingDirection)
        builder.remove(menu: .alignment)
        builder.remove(menu: .toolbar)
        builder.remove(menu: .sidebar)
        builder.remove(menu: .fullscreen)
        builder.remove(menu: .minimizeAndZoom)
        builder.remove(menu: .bringAllToFront)

    }
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
}
```

Hope this helps, Cheers

Comment: Is it required to remove each item manually? Can you just remove top level identifiers instead?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible just yet, but I *think* Apple is planning to add APIs for `UIEditMenuInteraction` soon. This is what I found in the [WebKit source](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit) (mind the `WK_IOS_TBA` availability specifier):

```objectivec
/**
 * @abstract Called when the web view is about to present its edit menu.
 *
 * @param webView The web view displaying the menu.
 * @param animator Appearance animator. Add animations to this object to run them alongside the appearance transition.
 */
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView willPresentEditMenuWithAnimator:(id<UIEditMenuInteractionAnimating>)animator WK_API_AVAILABLE(ios(WK_IOS_TBA));

/**
 * @abstract Called when the web view is about to dismiss its edit menu.
 *
 * @param webView The web view displaying the menu.
 * @param animator Dismissal animator. Add animations to this object to run them alongside the dismissal transition.
 */
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView willDismissEditMenuWithAnimator:(id<UIEditMenuInteractionAnimating>)animator WK_API_AVAILABLE(ios(WK_IOS_TBA));
```

**UPDATE**: These methods are showing up in the `WKUIDelegate` docs too now:

- [webView(_:willPresentEditMenuWithAnimator:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/4104045-webview)
- [webView(_:willDismissEditMenuWithAnimator:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/4104044-webview)